# I want to do MS in USA, My GPA 2.74. will I be eligible?

Tags: masters, united-states, gpa

I want to do MS in USA, My GPA 2.74. will I be eligible? did anyone had same GPA?. your response is really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Unfortunately, we can't comment on individual people's chances of admission. But, in general, admission to grad school is very difficult with a sub-3.0 GPA.

Comment: Yes and no. But then we can't judge for you. Better go to Grad Cafe or somewhere like that.